# Make reset_password_token not requiered in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding

I am trying to override update method from `PasswordsController` from Devise to work for an api rest application (so from the client only come values for `password` and `password_confirmation`, without the value for `reset_password_token`). My question is: how to override `update` method to not require `reset_password_token`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because without the token, you cannot find the existing user record.

And then it's not clear for the app, for which user the password should be updated.